# tableViewCell の削除について

Tags: swift, xcode

tableViewCellをスワイプして削除したいのですが下の画像の様にdeleteを押したら致命的なエラーになる。どの様なコードを追加しなければならないですか。またそれは何故ですか。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

問題のあるコード↓↓

```
import UIKit

class TableViewController: UITableViewController {


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

       tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "TableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "customTableViewCell")

    }


    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "customTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell

        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    }


    //問題のある部分！
   override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if editingStyle == .delete {
　　　　　　　//おそらくarray.remove(at: indexPath.row)的な処理が必要であるはず、、

            tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
        }
    }

    @IBAction func addSkillButton(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    }


    @IBAction func secret(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    }


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

デバッグコンソールには **Internal Incosistency Exception** という表示がどこかに出ていたのではないでしょうか? 何らかのエラーメッセージが表示されている場合には、致命的なエラーとだけ言わずに、そのメッセージをご質問に含められた方が、より的確なアドバイスをより早く得ることにつながります。

今回の問題に関して言えば、結論はご自身のコメントにあるように「`array.remove(at: indexPath.row)`的な処理が必要」だと言うことです。

もう少し具体的に言うと、

1. `tableView(_:numberOfRowsInSection:)`が1を返している
2. `tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)`で、そのセクション内の行を削除したことがiOS側に伝えられる
3. iOSはそのセクションの行数が1から1減って0になっているのを期待してるのに、1が返ってくる
4. 辻褄が合わんやんけ(inconsistent)と怒られる

と言う状況になっています。

**どの様なコードを追加しなければならない** かと言えば、上記のような場合にも`tableView(_:numberOfRowsInSection:)`が辻褄の合う値を返すようにすること、と言うことになります。ご自身が書かれているように`array`を導入するのも1つの方法でしょう。

```
    //↓そのうちもっと複雑なものの配列が必要になるはずだが、お試しコードの間は整数の配列で十分
    var array: [Int] = [1,2,3,4,5]

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        //`array`が1つ削除されると返される値も1減るから辻褄が合う
        return array.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        //`dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:)`ではなく、
        //`dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:for:)`の方を使う
        //(現在のiOSだと、上の方を使っても「動いているように見える」ことがありますが、
        //他の部分をいじっているうちに突然落ちる、なんてことになります。)
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell

        cell.skillName.text = "〇〇〇〇〇〇\(array[indexPath.row])"
        cell.goalCountNumber.text = "20 : 00"

        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if editingStyle == .delete {
            array.remove(at: indexPath.row)
            //↑と↓は必ず対にして使う
            tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
        }
    }
```

**Internal Incosistency Exception** と言う奴は、少々慣れていても、「なんであかんのかわかれへん」と言うことがよくあるんですが、今回のあなたのコードだと明らかですね。

Comment: できました!  まさか  ` override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    } ` に原因があるとは微塵も思っていませんでした。　以後エラーコードもしっかり載せる様気をつけます。　　今さらではありますが、いつもわかりやすく明快に教えてくださり誠に誠に感謝しております。